# Class Loading in JAVA

Tags: java, class, loader

The Sequence of searching and loading of classes by Class-Loader is:

1. Bootstrap Class Loader
2. Extension Class Loader
3. Application Class Loader

Now if I create a user defined String class with constructor.

```
class String {
    public String(){
        System.out.println("This is user defined String Class");
    }
}
```

and then executes below code:

```
public class Checking {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){
        String s= new String();
    }
}
```

Output of above code is 
"This is user defined String Class"

Which means user defined class is loaded, which is loaded by Application Class-Loader

So, my question is If bootstrap is loaded first , why am I getting the that output?
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: The fully qualified name of your class is not java.lang.String. So it's a completely different class.

Comment: if i add full name of class , then there will not be an issue. However you will never see the kind of code i wrote above. But just want to verify the class loading mechanism of JVM

Comment: My point is that your String class doesn't have the same name as the standard java.lang.String class. So when you Java loads it, it can't find it in the bootstrap classpath or the extension classpath. The only location where it is present is the application classpath. your.own.String is not the same class name as java.lang.String. Java loads classes based on their fully quelified name, not based on their simple name. That's why their can be 5 different Element classes in the standard library only: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the line

`package java.lang`

on top of your code, and check again. You will notice that you get your expected result now.

The reason for this is, that the class name is always only used as fully qualified name, which consists of the package name and the class name. So in your case, `String` is a different class than `java.lang.String` and will therefore not be found in `rt.jar`

Comment: Did you add the string class to that package? Adding the Checking class to the package doesn't help.

Comment: How does JVM knows which class i want to access..whether user-defined String or java.lang.String.

Comment: It does not. It follows strict rules. You tell it to use `String`. It uses `String`.  The ONLY reason you can usually access `java.lang.String` without either using a fully qualified name *or* `import Java.lang.String` is, that the entire package `java.lang` is implicitely imported. However classes in your local namespace still shadow any imported classes - which is what happens here: Your class `String` shadows the import `java.lang.String`.

If you define your class within the package `java.lang`, the class loading rules you quoted in your quesiton will come in effect.

Comment: As you can see: There is never any uncertainty of which class to use.

Comment: ok, i think I got it , if we have user-defined String without fully qualified name and there are 2 classes with name String , JVM will pre-add the current package name to String Class and then search.

Comment: and if there is String class in some other package and we want to access it , we need to use import package name......that means explicit import shadows implicit import..............correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: Exactly that. Which is why moving your user defined class to `java.lang` should lead to the behaviour you expected in the first place - in this case, two classes are exactly the same, and the order of class loaders determines which one is loaded.

Comment: ANd yes, you are correct on shadowing of implicit imports by explicit imports as well.

Comment: Thanks Man for the help :)